# InternetAttemptConnect causing crash C++

Tags: c++, wininet

I have an app that uses the wininet libraries to do some server posting/requesting. 99.9% of the time it works perfectly, but once in a blue moon the app will crash on an invalid memory reference while attempting to do ::InternetAttemptConnect(NULL). Sorry that the description is rather vague, but does anyone have any ideas on what might trigger this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Are you obeying WinInet's multhithreading guarantees?  WinInet is only somewhat thread safe; see [this](http://groups.google.com/group/microsoft.public.inetsdk.programming.wininet/browse_thread/thread/8cf882060ad412a1/bde28a4732cf368b?q=wininet+thread-safe&_done=%2Fgroups%3Fq%3Dwininet+thread-safe%26hl%3Den%26lr%3D%26sa%3DN%26tab%3Dwg%26&_doneTitle=Back+to+Search&&d#bde28a4732cf368b) posting for more info.